# Get posts by followers laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, model, eloquent

I want to display a feed page for an authenticated user which shows the latest posts from users that they follow. I have a follow system set up already which has the following:

Tabels:

- Posts
- users
- follow

User model:

```
 public function follow() {  
    return $this->BelongsToMany( 'User', 'Follow' ,'follow_user', 'user_id');
}
```

Feed controller:

```
public function feed () {

    $user = (Auth::user());

        return View::make('profile.feed')->with('user',$user);

    }
```

Feed.blade

```
  @foreach ($user->follow as $follow)

 @foreach ($follow->posts as $post)

     //* post data here.

  @endforeach

 @endforeach
```

This is pulling in the posts from the users a user follows but, i have a problem. The foreach is returning a user and then their posts each time.

**What its doing now:**

Followed user 1

- Post 1
- Post 2
- Post 3 etc etc

Followed user 2

- Post 1
- Post 2
- Post 3 etc etc

**What i would like to display:**

- Followed User 1 Post 1
- Followed User 2 Post 1
- Followed User 2 Post 2
- Followed User 1 Post 2 etc etc

Any ideas?

Comment: On your model, how did you set up the relationship? Take a look at  [hasManyThrough](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#has-many-through) , it might be just what you need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<?php
        /**
         * Get feed for the provided user
         * that means, only show the posts from the users that the current user follows.
         *
         * @param User $user                            The user that you're trying get the feed to
         * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder   The latest posts
         */
        public function getFeed(User $user) 
        {
            $userIds = $user->following()->lists('user_id');
            $userIds[] = $user->id;
            return \Post::whereIn('user_id', $userIds)->latest()->get();
        }
```

First, you need to get the users that the current user follows and their `ids` so you can store it in `$userIds`.

Second, you need the feed to also contain your posts, So you add that to array too.

Third, You return the posts where the `poster` or `author` of that post is in that array that we got from the first step.

And grab them store them from newest to oldest.

Any questions are welcome!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This seem to be working, however i am just getting my data in the view: [{"id":118696,"category_id":"win","user":56031,"username": etc etc. How can i return the data to my view properly?

Comment: That function should be in either your model or your repository. And then you call that function from your controller store it in some variable and pass that through your `View::make()` function.

Comment: Vote up that answer if it helped you. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help so far :) i am having a hard time calling the function from my controller, can you help?

Comment: Nothing because i am getting this error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

Comment: https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=2309-fatal-error-tests-not-finished-maximum-function-nesting-level-o/0 Check this out.

Comment: Sorry forgot to accept your answer. Got it working fine in the end. Thanks for your help! (I would voteup too but i don't have enough rep).

Answer (score 3):

Just a correction for **Akar**'s answer:

For those who are here in 2020, instead of `lists` you must use `pluck`. it changed in newer versions of laravel.

```
public function getFeed(User $user) 
        {
            $userIds = $user->following()->pluck('user_id');
            $userIds[] = $user->id;
            return \Post::whereIn('user_id', $userIds)->latest()->get();
        }
```